# How are these AWS bucket policy permissions working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, serverless

I have the following bucket policy which is working, but it seems to me that the logic is reversed. Seems like 'ArnLike' should be 'ArnNotLike'.

The desired intent is that the user ids and the roles listed in the 'Condition' SHOULD be allowed access to the bucket. And that is what is happening. So it's working as desired, but since the 'Effect' is set to 'Deny' I don't understand why 'ArnLike' should not be 'ArnNotLike'.

Can someone help me understand why? Thanks.

The excerpt below is from my serverless.yml config file.

```
MyBucketPolicy:
  Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Action:
            - 's3:*'
          Effect: Deny
          Resource: !Join
            - ''
            - - !GetAtt MyBucket.Arn
              - '/*'
          Principal: '*'
          Condition:
            StringNotLike:
              'aws:userId':
                - ${cf:external-stack.Role1}:*
                - ${cf:external-stack.Role2}:*
                - !Ref AWS::AccountId
            ArnLike:
              'aws:role':
                - arn:aws:iam::*:role/${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-${self:custom.region}-lambdaRole
                - arn:aws:iam::*:role/another-lambda-${self:custom.stage}-${self:custom.region}-lambdaRole
```

Comment: What's the desired behaviour?

Comment: this is a Deny rule, perhaps that is why you are thinking it is working in reverse?  It's impossible to tell you unless you tell us what your expected behavior is.

Comment: Please provide information as to what's happening, so we can explain why :)

Comment: Thx for trying to help. Yes, it would help if I described what I'm trying to do. :-) I've updated my question. Sorry about that and thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

So the logic is incorrect. The 'matchers' within a Condition are anded together. So this will let anything have access.  :-) Argh.